# Solve this limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^1 nxe^{-nx}dx$

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

I would like to solve that limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to\infty}  \int_{0}^1  nxe^{-nx} dx$$

I would like to take the limit inside the integral but for doing this, I have to use Beppo Levi's theorem or Dominated convergence Theorem. 
But the sequence of function is not increasing so I cannot use Beppo Levi's theorem, am I correct?

Comment: You can integrate first then take limit.

Comment: Just use integration by parts first and then evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 5):

let $nx=t$,then we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}nxe^{-nx}dx=\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n}te^{-t}dt$$
so use L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}nxe^{-nx}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{n}te^{-t}dt}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{-n}=0$$
or
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{n}te^{-t}=\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-t}=\Gamma{(2)}=1$$